# IncompatibleClassChangeError at GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm getting an 'IncompatibleClassChangeError' exception when using the function 'createBlobInfo' in one of my classes:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expecting non-static method com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobInfoFactory.createBlobInfo(Lcom/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity;)Lcom/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobInfo;
at com.farmigo.impex.utils.blobstore.BlobstoreUtils.getBlobKeyOfFileName(BlobstoreUtils.java:156)
```

My code itself hasn't changed lately, and was working fine last week.
While suspecting it's some change in the gae class, I've updated my eclipse's gae plugins, but still nothing - at my local env it's working, but not when deployed to app engine.

Does anyone have an idea what can it be?

Answer (score 3):

Your code was compiled against older gae classes. There were changes to the these classes in later versions which you have adopted. Since these changes are not compatible with the code base that your code was compiled against. Solution would be to recompile your code with the latest gae classes.